# How to run an django app which is not under the current project?

Tags: python, django

Actually , I want to run the app which are not in the current project directory. Is it possible to run another app if i give a path to that folder.
Currently i have a project directory PROJECT, under it there is manage.py and  PROJECT--->settings.py,urls.py.

And I have an another app running at other directory, for example plugins-->App1, App2.
What i want, when i start the server in PROJECT directory. I want to dynamically configured the settings.py and urls.py of the current project, so that i can run other apps. If some one know how to deal with this type of problem please help me.

Comment: I have done it using the sys.path.insert(0,'your path').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. The path to your app in INSTALLED_APPS is any valid python path.

> A tuple of strings designating all applications that are enabled in this Django installation. Each string should be a dotted Python path to:
>
> an application configuration class, or a package containing a
>   application.

Docs: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps)

Comment: thanks for answering, But it is still giving me the Importerror: Import by filename is not supported.I dont know, how to resolve the error.